# Не выполняется запрос SQL flask pyodbc UPDATE и SELECT

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, flask

```
   print("Запись в бд..")
   query = "UPDATE product_info SET comment = ? WHERE product_id = (SELECT id FROM product WHERE name = ?)"
   dbCursor.execute(query, (comment, name,))
   #dbCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE ids (id bigint)")
   dbCursor.commit()
```

Запрос никак не выполняется, причем SELECT и UPDATE, страница не возвращается сервером flask, кроме `CREATE TABLE` не работает . Раньше все было нормально и данные в таблице обновлялись, сейчас не выходит. Все перепробовал, другие библиотеки (pypyodbc, pymssql, pyodbc) - безуспешно. СУБД MS SQL Server, причем эти запросы в самой СУБД выполняются без проблем, использую SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая что запрос на создание таблицы работает, а всё остальное вызывает ошибки, то смею предположить что у Вас **не выбрана** база данных, с таблицами которой Вы пытаетесь произвести действия. Посмотрите внимательнее на строку подключения или что там Вы используете.

Как вариант, попробуйте передать в query что то вроде:

```
 USE YOU_DATABASE_NAME GO UPDATE product_info SET comment = ? WHERE product_id = (SELECT id FROM product WHERE name = ?)
```

Если проблема останется, то советую запустить MS SQL Profiler и посмотреть, что вообще приходит на сервер от Вашего клиента.

Comment: SELECT все-таки работал когда я выбирал данные из таблицы и выводил на сайт, а когда хочу изменить значение записи в БД, используя UPDATE, то не работает. Я попробую ваше решение.

Comment: Как-то странно, потому что выборка в другом месте и функции работает, потом в том же месте, где UPDATE, я сделал выборку – не работает...

Comment: Ну в итоге получилось всё?

Comment: Оу, ды у вас может сервер ругнуться на UPDATE, если подзапрос вернёт больше 1 записи. Советую на IN поменять.

Comment: Все получилось, запросы стали работать, пришлось переписывать приложение заново. Для меня остается загадкой, почему оно не работало.